# MySQL sort by column and column value

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by, multiple-columns

I have a situation here, I am having a join of two tables to get records, where one table is storing key value pair in two different columns(wordpress user meta table).

So heres my query:

```
SELECT 
    um.user_id
FROM
    sl_job_applications as ja,
    sl_usermeta as um
WHERE
    um.user_id = ja.user_id
        AND ja.job_id = 3
        AND ja.STAGE = 'Application'
        AND ja.STATUS = 'In progress'
group by ja.user_id
order by case when (um.meta_key = 'CURRENT_TOTAL_EXPERIENCE') then -1 else 2 end,
         um.meta_value asc
LIMIT 0 , 50;
```

The order by is not working here, my data is

```
user_id             meta_key                       meta_value

3                   CURRENT_TOTAL_EXPERIENCE       6

4                   CURRENT_TOTAL_EXPERIENCE       2

5                   CURRENT_TOTAL_EXPERIENCE       1

6
```

I hope you understand my table data,

My above query returns
6,4,5,3

But I am expecting this output:
6,5,4,3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change the `order by` to have an aggregation function such as `max()` and the value:

```
order by min(case when (um.meta_key = 'CURRENT_TOTAL_EXPERIENCE') then -1 else 2 end),
         min(case when (um.meta_key = 'CURRENT_TOTAL_EXPERIENCE') then um.meta_value end) asc
LIMIT 0 , 50;
```

The first checks that the meta_key with that value exists.  The second extracts the value and does the sort.

Comment: Hey this is working, but just for knowledge if I want the blank value at last everytime, then what should I do?

Comment: @ntechi . . . changing to `min()` should fix that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT um.user_id
FROM sl_job_applications AS ja
INNER JOIN sl_usermeta AS um ON um.user_id = ja.user_id
WHERE ja.job_id = 3 AND ja.STAGE = 'Application' AND ja.STATUS = 'In progress'
GROUP BY ja.user_id
ORDER BY CASE WHEN (um.meta_key = 'CURRENT_TOTAL_EXPERIENCE') THEN -1 ELSE 2 END,
         CAST(um.meta_value AS SIGNED) ASC
LIMIT 0, 50
```